# How to read PDF templates using java OCR

Tags: java, pdf, ocr

Can some one suggest a solution for the below scenario ?

We have menus from restaurants. Each restaurant has its own menu. The goal is to identify the elements in the menu such as menu item, toppings, prices etc and update the database.

Fox example : A restaurant menu can contain menu items such as "Chicken", "Vegetarian" etc under a group called "Sandwiches.

For that I am planning to use a java implementation of OCR. Will this work out ?

Comment: Do you have the document in a proper PDF already? If so, you can use something like PDFBox to parse out the information. If you actually need to scan the image, it's a lot more complex, and I'm not familiar with the java implementations for that. But for handling PDF documents with text and objects, I've been using PDFBox. PDFClown I also use in one scenario where I need to scan large parts of pages, might be something else you want to look into.

Comment: Is this an existing project or a new venture?

Comment: The PDF is the exact scan of the restaurant menu.

Answer (score 1):

If u want to use OCR inside your code you can go with [**Tessrect-OCR**](http://code.google.com/p/tesjeract/) with some native developement.Its a very powerfull library with having quick output.this link is for wrapper class for Tessrect or you can also use [Tess4j](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/) alternative to Tesjeract(first one).This is the same library used by google and u can also add multiple languages support.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the PDF to an image (using javacv etc) and OCR it using tesseract or tess4j. It is not a permanent or the best solution, but it works great!

Comment: Tess4J, with GhostScript installed, can recognize PDF by converting it to images before performing OCR.

Answer (score 0):

If you are typing up the PDF, then using it, there's no need to do this; simply read the PDF (see below). However, if you are scanning in the PDF (an image, not text), you will need to resort to OCR.

To read the PDF from a file, you could use something like [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) or [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting project! Java or any other language, I would think that OCR is not accurate enough for what you need. Menus are often printed with non-standard fonts and sometimes with background images making it difficult for OCR to accurately read every word. Then you have the challenge of formatting. Some menus may organize the content by Chicken, Vegetarian, Beef. Others may have categories like Light Fare, Entree, Appetizer, small plates.

This strikes me as a real data engineering challenge. While menus seem like they are hierarchical, they actual structure is very flexible and varies a great deal from one to another. Adding OCR to this mess adds typos to this whole mess, and now you need to be looking for words like "chicken" because you may actually have Chicen or Cichen or (h1ckn.

Maybe I've never used really great OCR software and I'm imagining a problem that isn't there. I would think that most restaurants type their menus on computers and you are better off trying to get them to share those files with you.